# SQL Indexing slower when forced

Tags: php, mysql, sql, windows

if i have the following table:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

and i do:

```
SELECT * FROM employees FORCE INDEX (first_name) WHERE first_name = 'Shem'
```

this query on a table with first_name indexed is slower than running the statement:

```
SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name = 'Shem'
```

on the following table:

```
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| emp_no     | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| birth_date | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| first_name | varchar(14)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| last_name  | varchar(16)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| gender     | enum('M','F') | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| hire_date  | date          | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

Why would using an index and forcing mySQL to use that index be slower than not having any index on first_name at all? Shouldn't this be faster?

***EXPLAINS***

**SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name = 'Shem' (no index)**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  |rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ALL  | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL |299733 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+-
```

**SELECT * FROM employees FORCE INDEX(first_name) WHERE first_name = 'Shem' (index)**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ref  | first_name    | first_name | 44      | const |  235 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
```

**SELECT * FROM employees WHERE first_name = 'Shem' (index)**

```
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
| id | select_type | table     | type | possible_keys | key        | key_len | ref   | rows | Extra                 |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | employees | ref  | first_name    | first_name | 44      | const |  235 | Using index condition |
+----+-------------+-----------+------+---------------+------------+---------+-------+------+-----------------------+
```

*timed results:*

```
no index:
2.7541568279266

index - forced:
2.827162027359

index - no force: 
2.721155166626
```

Comment: What `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` shows?

Comment: How big is your table? How many rows and average row width in bytes?

Comment: **They all drag their feet when forced**...

Comment: @CORRUPT i've added the explain SELECT above

Comment: @mvp i have around 300 000 entries in the employees table...

Comment: What indexes do you have in this table? (And why would you create two indexes for the `first_name` column?)

Comment: @Arjan i didn't create two, i've only created one, and then i've dropped the one i created. I've tried dropping twice but the second time i get an error saying that i can't drop what doesn't exists. so i'm not sure what the second index is :S as you can see from my table structure, the index is either there or not... Also the last query which does not force the use of the index (even though it exists) runs the fastest..

Comment: Please show all your indexes. Your fast query is using index `first_name_2`, and slow query is using index `first_name`. You may want to drop all indexes (except for primary key) and recreate it using `CREATE INDEX employees_first_name_idx ON employees(first_name);`

Comment: @mvp sorry, that was my mistake while rushing to get the explains out... i've updated it, my results are no different though. forcing the index is still slower

Comment: @CodeAngry could you expand on that?

Comment: @BlueMonster Nobody likes to be forced. If you get them to do what you want willingly, you win! :) - *(ignore me, liked your question title so much had to troll it)*

Comment: @CodeAngry LOL! nice, i actually laughed out loud

Comment: Your results are all within 3% discrepancy. Did you try to run it more than once? Maybe there is no problem here at all

Comment: What bothers me more in this example is that the result without any index is as fast as the ones with index. Seems as MySQL is doing a full table scan here even when there's an index to use.